# Как обновить таблицу из другого класса?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, realm

Текст большой, но я максимально описал ситуацию.

Есть `NewPostsTableViewController`. Сама таблица заполняется данными из Realm. А в Realm данные записываются из JSON.

Сейчас все работает таким образом:

1. Устанавливаем и запускаем приложение;
2. Запущенное приложение забирает данные из JSON и записывает их в Reaml;
3. Данные в таблице не отображаются;
4. Закрываем и запускаем приложение;
5. Вот тут уже таблица заполнена данными из предыдущего запуска приложения, а после выполняется пункт 2;

Если говорить коротко, то таблица отображает записи из Realm, а в Realm записи успешно записываются.

Проблема лишь в том, что запись в Realm происходит после заполнения данными таблицы, а обновить таблицу после уже не выходит.

Теперь перейдем к коду. В `NewPostsTableViewController` внутри метода `viewDidLoad` вызываю функцию:

```
func loadPosts () {
    NewPost().loadData { (posts: [NewPost.Model]) in
        self.posts = posts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Тут получаем массив записей и обновляем таблицу. Данные для массива берутся из Realm. Этот код рабочий.

Идем дальше. Тут я придерживаюсь такой логики - раз функция выше успешно забирает данные и обновляет таблицу, то почему бы ее не вызвать в другом месте!?

Так вот. В классе `NewPost` есть еще один метод - `loadNewData`. В этом методе как раз и происходит парс JSON, а затем и запись в Realm.

В самом конце этого метода я прописываю это:

```
let newPostsTableViewController = NewPostsTableViewController()
newPostsTableViewController.loadPosts()
```

По идее этот код должен заново получить массив из Realm, а затем обновить ячейки таблицы.

Но этого не происходит. Вот тут и возникает вопрос - что я сделал не так и как правильно это сделать? Я постарался максимально подробно описать всю ситуацию. Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этим

```
let newPostsTableViewController = NewPostsTableViewController()
newPostsTableViewController.loadPosts()
```

Вы создаете новый объект класса и вызываете его метод. Он никак не связан с тем, который у Вас.

Для вызова из другого класса используйте протоколы.

Ну а в Вашей ситуации оберните в `DispatchQueue`:

```
func loadPosts () {
    NewPost().loadData { (posts: [NewPost.Model]) in
        self.posts = posts
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Измените например так метод получения новых данных:

```
func loadNewData(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    let url: String = self.prepareApiUrl(controller: "post", method: "novelties")
    request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        saveNewData(data: response.result.value!)
        completion()
    }
}
```

и там где вызываете `loadNewData`:

```
...loadNewData { [weak self] in
    self?.loadPosts()
}
```

Comment: Добавил `DispatchQueue`, но теперь, возможно, глупый вопрос: `newPostsTableViewController.loadPosts()` - это я оставляю? Просто я добавил `DispatchQueue`, загрузил и запустил приложение, но данные в таблице не обновились...

Comment: @Colibri значит нужно проверить, все ли правильно сделано. Данные точно забираются? Меняется содержимое self.posts? Для tableView правильно все сделали? Прописали delegate, dataSource?

Comment: я извиняюсь, а зачем обновлять таблицу в асинхронном потоке?

Comment: Да, все есть. Данные отображаются в таблице, они просто не обновляются после парса. То есть запускается приложение, заполняется таблица, а дальше происходит парс и добавление в Realm новых данных. Вот эти новые данные будут в таблице только после перезапуска приложения, а надо как-то реализовать обновление таблицы после парса.

Comment: @Colibri Вы таблицу заполняете из posts? Немного неправильно еще понял, loadData отрабатывает нормально, а loadNewData нет? Покажите loadNewData.

Comment: @Colibri вам нужно использовать протоколы однозначно и с помощью этого протокола передавать объекты. И в классе где вы реализуете этот протокол там же обновляйте таблицу. Это сложно, но вам надо разобраться с протоколами.

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов по описанию понятно, что данные забираются из базы, обычно база используется для большого объема данных, т.е. данные получаем в фоновом потоке. Для reload таблицы нам нужно ее дернуть из UI потока. Достаточно и колбека как в loadData, но нужно посмотреть что в loadNewData

Comment: @VAndrJ вот методы: http://pastebin.com/ZThdxVt1

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов а вы уверены, что нужно использовать протоколы? Я по сути хочу просто-напросто вызвать метод в Классе2, который лежит в Классе1.

Comment: @Colibri обновил ответ

Comment: @VAndrJ все верно. Вышло идеально.